# how do you remove the index from a dataframe before using xlwriter to convert the dataframe to a excel file

Tags: python, pandas

Love using pandas to manipulate data but I am having some trouble.

Whenever I output a dataframe as a file, the index remains. I would like to remove it, and have the first column in column A of the excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `index` keyword argument to `False`:

```
df.to_excel( ..., index=False)
```

See the docs of `to_excel` for all arguments: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html